# Android random countdown app

Tags: android, random, numbers

I previously made simple reaction-time app thing on my TI 84 calculator, and realized that it was so simple I should be able to make it for android, too.

But I'm not really skilled in android yet thus not knowing some program parts, and I really don't know how to make it al together..

This is what I would like to make: An app that, when pressing the start button, Picks a random number (from 1000 to 4000) And then counts down from 6000 milliseconds to x(1000-4000)

Though I have gotten no idea how to do this and can't find how to make a random number the same as milliseconds on internet..

Could you please give an example code of the random number and countdown part? For example how to make the random number count the same as milliseconds? I don't know how fast android calculates..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For creating Random numbers, you can do this:

```
Random random=new Random();
int var=random.nextInt(maxRange-minRange)+minRange;
```

`maxRange` and `minRange` defines the number range, in your case 4000 and 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the button click. On button click, get a random number and start timer.
On timer time up, do what ever you need to do.

```
// Get your button
Button btnStartCounting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartCounting);

btnStartCounting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Random r= new Random();
        int number = 6000 - (r.nextInt(3000) + 1000);

        CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(number, number) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
               // Time Up. Do Sth!

            }
        };
        timer.start();

    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you, but eclipse gives an error at onclicklistener, and its not an import issue..

Comment: Where in the code do i have to put it? I have pasted it after the setcontent view, but get an error at that onclicklistener... do i have to use public something?

Comment: You can only use onclicklistener on a button(view), did you get your button instance? Updated my answer...

Comment: Yea, somehow i fixed it by removing override, and not yet putting the button in (i can fix that later) Though, when i start the app, it loads the first screen then instantly goes to the next screen, while i set the timer to 100 000 ..... Do you know why?

Comment: @Bart, You should understand, that Stackoverflow is not a place where people write free code for you. People can point to the right direction with their answers, but noone's gonna give you a complete working solution. After all, you're a programmer, aren't you?

Comment: Yea, i was being very 'rude' and impatient, I understand that after looking back. I am really sorry as i said (edited post) in my new thread, and I hope you guys are still willing to help me in the new thread..